# How to install QGIS 1.8 plugin QGIS2KML?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to download QGIS2KML plugin.

I went to Plugins → Fetch Python Plugins in the Repositories tab and pasted the url.

It claimed that it was successfully downloaded, however, QGIS2KML was not installed in my  ~/qgis/python/plugins folder.

[image]

As a result from my failed attempt, I manually downloaded QGIS2KML and extracted it to my ~/qgis/python/plugins folder. Now QGIS2KML is shown as installed:

[image]

But I am still unable to see QGIS2KML icon.

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to upgrade to QGIS v.2.8.x and work with the large amount of enhancements and new features?

Comment: @gcarrilo I want to use the QGIS2KML plugin, which is only compatible with 1.8. According to research, 2.8 does not have a plugin similar to that of QGIS2KML. As a result, I've download an other version to use this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

its kind of weird the situation that you have over there, if there is no icon (shortcut) the qgis2kml plugin should located on Plugins Dropdown MENU

[image]